# dataframe spark scala take the (MAX-MIN) for each group

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have a dataframe from a processing part, looks like :

```
   +---------+------+-----------+
|Time     |group |value      |
+---------+------+-----------+
|    28371|    94|        906|
|    28372|    94|        864|
|    28373|    94|        682|
|    28374|    94|        574|
|    28383|    95|        630|
|    28384|    95|        716|
|    28385|    95|        913|
```

i would like to take the (value for max time - value for min time) for each group, to have this result :

```
+------+-----------+
|group |  value    |
+------+-----------+
|    94|       -332|
|    95|        283|
```

Thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df.groupBy("groupCol").agg(max("value")-min("value"))
```

Based on the question edit by the OP, here is a way to do this in PySpark. The idea is to compute the row numbers in ascending and descending order of time per group and use those values for subtraction.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
w_asc = Window.partitionBy(df.groupCol).orderBy(df.time)
w_desc = Window.partitionBy(df.groupCol).orderBy(func.desc(df.time))
df = df.withColumn(func.row_number().over(w_asc).alias('rnum_asc')) \
       .withColumn(func.row_number().over(w_desc).alias('rnum_desc'))
df.groupBy(df.groupCol) \
  .agg((func.max(func.when(df.rnum_desc==1,df.value))-func.max(func.when(df.rnum_asc==1,df.value))).alias('diff')).show()
```

It would have been easier if window function `first_value` were available in Spark SQL. A generic way to solve this using SQL is

```
select distinct groupCol,diff
from (
select t.*
      ,first_value(val) over(partition by groupCol order by time) - 
       first_value(val) over(partition by groupCol order by time desc) as diff
from tbl t
) t
```

Comment: it is unfair to change the question after it is answered. anyways, provided an answer.

Comment: You're right and i'm sorry about this. I'm very grateful to you, it's very clear and i understand how to proceed, thank you